# Reliably detect caller domain over cURL request?

Tags: php, web-services, security, curl, dns

OK so server-side security is not my forte. Basically, I'm building a service which users may use (via an SDK) only on the domain they stipulated when they signed up.

The SDK calls my web service over cURL in PHP.

Would I be right in thinking I cannot reliably detect the caller domain, i.e. enforce that it is the same domain they stipulated when signing up?

cURL of course sends this over headers, but headers can always (?) be faked.

Is there a better course of action to enforce domain for this sort of thing?

(NB I'm already using an API key, too - it's just I wanted to restrict domain, too)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Editorial: If you ask me, I wouldn't do this. There are cases where domains and IPs can change (cloud based services, load balancers, proxies, emergency server moves, emergency IP address changes...). With something like this, you're putting  customers in danger of a lot of trouble. I personally would refrain from purchasing your product if it came with a check that can freeze my site's operations   if something changes on my end. What if I can't reach you because it's the weekend, or night in your time zone?

Comment: That's a fair point - thanks. Equally, though, I have an interest in preventing my service from being misused by being shared across multiple domains. Is this just something I should live with and trust people? After all, thinking about it, it's not like I hand out my API keys for the services I use, for others to use at my expense...

Comment: I guess that depends on your line of business and your customer base. I tend to have more trust where reasonably sized organizations are involved. Cheating is risky for them: a disgruntled intern could bring everything down. Smaller customers, though, I don't know. It really depends on your situation.

Comment: I think what you can do is analyse the data on daily basis using scripts to check the ips to api mapping and see if it doesnt match with the initial settings.I assume that it will match in most of the cases ..

Comment: as IP-domain mapping doesnt change often

Comment: Thanks, both. I'll give this some more thought.

Comment: @Utkanos Have you got any solution with that because i am doing the same.

Comment: Nope - as the answer below says, IP is the only real thing you can detect.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you get from a cURL call is the remote IP in the `REMOTE_ADDR` environment variable.

AFAIK, that is *very* hard to fake meaningfully (ie. when the caller wants to actually receive data.)

So if you can live with limiting the customer to an *IP*, you should be reasonably safe by checking that variable.

However, of course, that gives you no control over which domain they use the data for. That's not reasonably possible - an IP can be used for multiple domains.

You could, however, try to resolve a domain name to its IP, and compare that to the `REMOTE_ADDR` you are getting.

I don't think this is a good idea overall; see my comment above.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So it sounds like restricting someone to a particular domain, i.e. preventing them using the same account on another domain, is not really feasible...